# About Gemini Sub-Accounts features

Tags: cryptocurrency, gemini

I have an app that is planning to integrate with Gemini to provide my client the investment capabilities with crypto currency.

I just registered a personal account in the Gemini sandbox environment and generated a master key api to work with Gemini API. https://docs.gemini.com/rest-api/#using-master-api-keys

I hope that all clients in my app can link to individual Gemini Account to buy, sell, and transfer crypto currency as they can. In order to do that, we are planning to use Gemini Sub-Accounts Features to create multiple Gemini accounts off of primary account and link them with our app's users.  After that, our app's user can add a new bank, deposit funds to their Gemini account and make a crypto order.

I am not sure that sub-account features can adapt to my purpose. I am not sure that Gemini sub-account features are suitable for my purpose. I assume that your app's users could be up to approximately 1 million or higher.

1. Do I just need to register one Gemini Personal Account?
2. Can we create 1 million Gemini sub-accounts or higher off of the primary account and link them to each user in our application?
3. Add a new personal bank corresponding to each Gemini sub-accounts?

Comment: I'm trying to find out the same, please paste it here once you got the solution.